# STM32 Analog Output

Tags: stm32f4discovery, dac, digital-analog-converter

I was making a research about analog output from stm32. STM32F407VG user manual and DAC Manual says that STM32 can give analog output from DAC periphal.

Is that analog output really ANALOG ?

Comment: "Really analog" as opposed to something like PWM, which is called "analog" on Arduinos?

Comment: I think a digital supply can't generate analog signal. That is why i said "really analog".

Answer (score 2):

That is the idea of the analogue peripherals to be analogue.

Digital ones have two states - `0` and `1`.

Analogue ones can have more than one state. The DAC can have as many states as is the resolution of the DAC data register. If DAC has 12 bits resolution it can have 4096 states.

In the fact is not "fully analogue" output only 4096 states output which we can consider as analogue.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the DAC (digital to analog converter) on an STM32 is "really analog" in the sense that it generates any voltage between 0 and the supply voltage. The two DACs in the STM32F407 are 12-bit DACs, which means they can generate 4096 different voltage levels in that range.

Furthermore, the DAC outputs in the STM32F407 can be buffered, which means they can source or sink some current, making the output "look" no different than the output from a typical analog component such as an op amp.

So even though the signal may be generated by digitally controlled mosfets and resistors, it will behave just like a "real" analog signal.

Answer (score 0):

This "analog" is created by "digital" (1-0) toggling of a pin in a very short period of time which is called "PWM".
So it's originally digital but when you do it real fast it "feels" analog.

[image: you can see a demonstration of PWM in this picture]